# get button id from js file and use in another js file - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which alerts when a button is clicked

1.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#label1, #label2, #button1').click(function () {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

`#label1` and `#label2` are used in html file, but `#button1` is used in javascript file like:

2.js

```
...
return '<button id="button1" type="button" onclick="ReasignClicked(' +data.record.batch_id + ')" val="' +data.record.batch_id + '" )">Reasign</button> ';
...
```

when I click label, it is alerting but when I click button it is not alerting.

Any recommendation?

Comment: where is your ReasignClicked() function?

Comment: What is the order of the JS file links in your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Return following and try.

```
return '<button id="button1" type="button" onclick="ReasignClicked(' +data.record.batch_id + ')" val="' +data.record.batch_id + '" )">Reasign</button> 
<script>$("#button1").click(function () {alert("clicked");});</script>'
```

change ready()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#label1, #label2').click(function () {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `on("click"...` and it is working

```
$(document).on("click",'#label1, #label2, #button1', function () {
   alert('clicked');
});
```